# compare two txt files

Tags: perl, list, file

I'm new to Perl. I have two text files and I need to check matching string on both lists.

For example matching strings are:

```
line - file 1: fe/bla/blablabla/abcdefg
```

```
line - file 2: blablabla/abcdefg
```

There is a match!

In addition, the location (line number) of the matching strings is not the same on both files.

I tried put the lists in arrays and compare the arrays with nested loop, but the running time of the program is huge (the lists contain thousand of lines) and I believe there is another way, less naïve and more productive.

This is the way I put the data in the array:

```
my $list1 = /path/to/the/file;

open (FILE , '<' , $list1) or die ("Could not open the file");
while ( my $line = <FILE> ) {
  chomp ($line);
  $list_1[$i] = $line;
  $i = $i+1;
}
close FILE;
```

I did it to the other list as well.

And this is my nested loop.

```
for ( $k = 0 ; $k < @list_1 ; $k = $k+1 ) {
  for ($i = 0 ; $i < @list_2 ; $i = $i+1 ) {
    if (index($list_1[$k] , $list_2[$i]) != -1) {
      splice (@list_2 , $i , 1);
      last;
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: What have you got so far? And what problem are you having? For finding duplicates, the tool for the job in perl is a `hash`.

Comment: You say that you've tried putting the lists in arrays - can you add this to the question?

Comment: The problem I have is that its taking too long time to run.

Comment: Add some more example with and without matches. Make sure to format it correctly. Explain what exactly matches and why.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. One of the lists contain substrings of the second  list. I want to find out which of the strings have substrings on the second list. example: /blabla/abcdef/gh      /abd/hf - this is not match... there is example for match in my question.

Comment: Are the strings in list2 always *substrings* of those in list1? What result do you want from this program? Please give a reasonable set of test data and the result you expect from it.

Comment: The code you have written is wrong because you shouldn't modify a loop that you are iterating over (`@list_2`). If you remove an element as well as incrementing `$i` then you will skip an element of the list.

Answer (score 2):

As long as `file2` isn't enormous, the simplest way is to build a regular expression pattern from its contents and check each line in `file1` against the pattern.

You don't say what output you want, so I have printed all lines in `file1` that have a match in `file2`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

my ($list1, $list2) = qw( /path/to/list1 /path/to/list2 );

open my $fh, '<', $list2;
my $re = join '|', map { chomp; quotemeta; } <$fh>;
$re = qr/$re/;

open $fh, '<', $list2;
while ( <$fh> ) {
  print if /$re/;
}
```

Comment: @or89: You're welcome. Does it run in a reasonable time?